After upgrading to 24.10, the display is garbled
Old laptop but has always worked well with Ubuntu until now. After upgrading 24.04 Ubuntu Desktop version this morning to 24.10, it gives the graphic logo screens and the login during boot, but then the desktop is totally unreadable although the cursor arrow is still sharp and clear. This system has an ATI Radeon Xpress 200M display using an AMD Turion64 mobile processor. Running sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall in Terminal the cursor drops to the next line, then just sits there blinking but nothing ever happens.
Running sudo lshw -C display shows a number of lines with product: RS480M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200] and, skipping some lines, logical name: /dev/fb0 and version: 00. Any ideas how to get passed this and have a usable screen? I don’t care if it’s high resolution (it’s not used for gaming or multimedia) as long as it works.


When you tested the system with live media, did it operate as expected?  On older hardware (esp. graphics hardware) problems can be encountered with newer kernels, so one option would be using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with the GA kernel stack (HWE will soon advance to 6.11 too (its in edge-proposed currently) thus why I'm suggesting GA kernel stack). You mention upgrade but don't say from what; and I'm assuming you booted live media using 6.11 kernel prior to release-upgrade or install of that kernel (mostly as I would)

Live media worked fine but I didn’t upgrade that way. The system prompted for an upgrade so I let it do it. I can find no sign that any Nvidia drivers are installed but if they are, how can they be removed and replaced with something generic?

I usually use lshw to display what I'm using and it shows me two cards on this box; one using the i915 kernel module & the other using the generic radeon kernel module from the driver= detail. You don't say what is used; only provide the textual responses obtained when the app probed your hardware (the text detail is more for us humans; often ignored by software); capabilities, configuration & resources lines being most useful to system.  Yeah I'd expect ubuntu-drivers autoinstall to give a message such as "All the available drivers are already installed" but can't help there sorry
